# Cannot assign "'4'": "Element.value_code" must be a "Value" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to save element.value_code, but this error occurs. If I get the value_code on the getlist, my mission will be over. How should I correct this error? I'd really appreciate it if you could let me know.

Error:

```
Cannot assign "'4'": "Element.value_code" must be a "Value" instance.
```

***models.py***

There were only models related to Value and Element, but we added all models to help you understand why option_code and designated_code exist.

```
class Option(models.Model):
    option_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    product_code = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='product_code')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['option_code']

class Value(models.Model):
    value_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    option_code = models.ForeignKey(Option, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='option_code')
    product_code = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='product_code')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    extra_cost = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['value_code']

class Designated(models.Model):
    designated_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_code = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='product_code')
    price = models.IntegerField()
    rep_price = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['designated_code']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.designated_code)

class Element(models.Model):
    element_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    designated_code = models.ForeignKey(Designated, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='designated_code')
    value_code = models.ForeignKey(Value, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='value_code', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['element_code']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.element_code)
```

***views.py***

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = ElementForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        for value_code2 in request.POST.getlist('value_code2'):
            element = Element()
            element.designated_code = Designated.objects.get(product_code=id)
            element.value_code = value_code2
            element.save()

    else:
        element = Element()
        element.designated_code = Designated.objects.get(product_code=id)
        element.value_code = None
        element.save()
```

***forms.py***

```
class ElementForm(forms.Form):
    value_code2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(error_messages={'required': "옵션을 선택하세요."}, label="옵션", queryset=Value.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending `PK` or `ID` to your url.

For making relation between those sent `PK`s and your `Element` model, you should give `Element` an object of `Value`, not its `PK`

And when you use `for value_code2 in request.POST.getlist('value_code2')`, `value_code2` is `PK` and it's wrong

Your solution can be that after passing data to `ElementForm`, this returns you some `cleaned_data` if `form.is_valid()`. And in that `cleaned_data` there should be `Value` object:

```py
...
if form.is_valid():
    element = Element()
    element.designated_code = Designated.objects.get(product_code=id)
    element.value_code = form.cleaned_data['value_code2']
    element.save()
```

Read about `cleaned_data` in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data

Comment: Thank you for the information. You've solved the problem.